# Does WebClient use KeepAlive?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, keep-alive

I need to issue around 50 HTTP requests to a single host (API calls). Performance is important, so I'd like to use HTTP KeepAlive's. Does WebClient support this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It does on my machine, but I can't see that it's *documented* to. I'd certainly expect it to by default. The simplest way to tell is to run [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) (or Fiddler) and look at exactly what's going down the wire.

For example, this program:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            string text = client.DownloadString("http://www.microsoft.com");
            Console.WriteLine(text.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Generates a first request of:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1   
Host: www.microsoft.com    
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Subsequence requests are just:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.microsoft.com
```

... presumably because once a connection is in KeepAlive mode, it's assumed it will stay that way.

Comment: I've noticed some odd behavior when using UploadData, for some reason the client's headers are reset when the response bytes are returned.

Comment: @Oliver: It's not really clear what you mean by that, but if it's something that's causing you problems, you may want to ask a new question.

Comment: It's not really an issue just thought I'd put a note about some behavior I'd seen. Behavior is as follows Create WebClient -> Add Headers to Dictionary -> Make UploadData call -> Headers will be empty, seems they get nuked for some reason.

Answer (score 18):

As documented here, WebClient makes use of WebRequest in its private implementation, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx. Microsoft does not expose that as a public property for you to control.

Therefore, reviewing its implementation using Reflector you can see how KeepAlive is set for the WebRequest object in use. Like @Jon pointed out, an experiment shows that KeepAlive is set to true. This matches other scenarios too, such as .NET remoting's private implementation.

In rare cases you may find KeepAlive = true can lead to SocketException, and then you have to use reflection or other tricks to set it to false which is very annoying.

Comment: You don't need to use reflection, you can just inherit, override GetWebRequest() and set some properties on the WebRequest after calling base.GetWebRequest() in the overridden method

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2