# Persistent HTTP Connection with RestSharp

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, keep-alive, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to consume a REST web service and will be making a large volume of calls in a short time period.

The documentation for the API strongly recommends the use of persistent HTTP connections to do this, however I am struggling to get this working with RestSharp.

I have tried adding the "Connection: Keep-alive" header to the request but when I do this the request fails with the following error - "Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property."

Can I not use this header with RestSharp or is there something else I need to do to enable this?

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Post some of your code (to show how you are using RestSharp). I've used RestSharp quite a bit and never had a problem with connections closing prematurely.

Comment: I'm just using standard RestSharp connection code, with the generic Execute<T> method. To add the keep-alive header i'm just attempting request.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive"); but this fails as described above.

Comment: How can you solved this issue. [I have the same problem](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/781)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a good answer, you need to ask a good question. Where in the documentation does it say this? (Link/Reference?) How many requests is a "large volume"? Also, if you post your code for how you added `Connection: Keep-Alive` to your http headers, someone here may be able to comment on your technique and help you with the specific programming issue.

Also, `Connection: Keep-Alive` may already be present on the outgoing HttpRequests! Check it out using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/). I've seen a few blog posts with wireshark captures of RestSharp requests that had the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header present without any extra config. For example, while testing other mvc3 functionality using RestSharp as a consumer, [Jimmy Bogard](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/24/model-binding-xml-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) captures his RestSharp requests with fiddler which already have the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header.

Apparently it is also the default behavior for built in .Net classes like [System.Net.Webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient) to use `Connection: Keep-Alive`. Reference [Does WebClient use KeepAlive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699013/does-webclient-use-keepalive)

I think that making use of keep alive is going to be more about your code using RestSharp in an optimal manner than it is about configuring RestSharp itself. If you want to make sure your connection is reused you need to make sure your use of RestSharp allows for that by keeping one RestClient instance in scope and reusing it throughout multiple requests against the same host.

Again using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will help you capture some HttpRequests for analysis.